# High-Dimensional Topology vs. Low-Dimensional Topology: What are the hard questions in the former?

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

This is a somewhat vague/non-technical question.

I've heard a lot about how the topology of manifolds (smooth or otherwise) is simpler in dimension at least 5, due to the applicability of surgery theory and things like the h-cobordism theorem. In particular, questions such as classification of simply-connected manifolds are much more easily solved in dimension at least 5. Is this a general phenomenon in (geometric) topology? Or are there some natural questions about manifolds which have easier answers in dimension 3 and 4 than in dimension greater than 5? If so, what is an example?

(I've heard that (Riemannian) geometry can be harder in high dimension, but I'm curious if there are more purely topological questions)

Thanks!

Comment: I think dimension 4 is the hardest in all regards. A better question would be about problems solved in dimensions $<4$ and open in dimensions $>3$.

Answer (score 4):

1. Algorithmic PL homeomorphism problem for compact manifolds is solvable in dimensions $<4$, is unsolvable in higher dimensions.
2. Borel conjecture holds in dimensions $<4$, is wide open in higher dimensions.
3. Smith conjecture is proven in dimension 3, fails in higher dimensions.
4. A good classification of compact manifolds is known in dimensions $<4$, is hopeless in higher dimensions.

Comment: I read often point 4, but I don't understand it. I am aware about word problem in group theory and its link with isomorphism problem in topology, but it only implies that such a classification cannot be algorithmic; why a non-algorithmic classification wouldn't be good?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to leave the question open in case somebody can come up with something that works in 4 dimensions but not >4.

Comment: @Seirios: Any kind of "classification" in dimensions $\ge 4$ would have to include a "classification" of arbitrary finitely-presented groups. Setting aside algorithmic issues, such "classification" is hopeless. Compare this with Thurston's geometrization conjecture/Perelman's theorem - this is what I mean by a "classification": You break manifolds into simpler pieces in a (more or less canonical) fashion and then describe topology of these pieces. On the other hand, topological simply-connected 4-manifolds are classified by Freedman's work...

Comment: On yet another hand, the situation with smooth 4-manifolds is (at least currently) quite mysterious, it is not even clear what invariants would be.

Comment: There are full classifications of highly connected smooth $n$-manifolds for all $n>4$ now, I believe, where highly connected means $\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor$-connected. Of course this is still very mysterious for $n=4$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm far from an expert on this, but apparently the question
"Does there exist a compact $n$-manifold not homeomorphic to a simplicial complex?" fits your criteria.

In dimension 3 or less, the answer is "**no**", and this is well known.

In dimension 4, the answer is "**yes**", for example the $E_8$ manifold, and this is a difficult result (due to Freedman) but it has been known since the '80s.

In dimension 5 or greater it was not known until last year, when Manolescu answered in the negative.

For a bit of history on this problem, wikipedia is a good place to start:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptvermutung

Comment: Secretly this is really a low-dimensional topology question. Galewski and Stern showed the question was equivalent to a question about the homology cobordism group $\Theta_3^{\mathbb Z}$ - and it's this question that Manolescu answered (using the low-dimensional techniques of gauge theory).